# Is there a word that can be used to refer to a collection of "donations" or "payments"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm developing a product which is essentially a payment system. In this system, an organization can create a *campaign* and this *campaign* can be publicly shared to accept either *donations* or *payments*.

To be more specific, a *campaign* can be created by an organization to:

- accept *donations* for a particular cause
- accept *payments* for a particular service or product

What would be a good word to use, instead of *campaign*, that would cover both cases? It must be very intuitive and self-explanatory.

Comment: Funding, do you mean?

Comment: Something like that, yes. Does it make sense saying "I created this fund to accept donations/payments for X"?

Comment: It might be worth reading about [revenue model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revenue_model)

Comment: Your title question and your body-text question conflict. Do you mean 'What would be a good word to use, instead of _donations_ and _payments_, that would cover both cases? In which case, simply 'monies'.

Comment: Thanks Edwin, I updated the title, hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider [**funding**](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/funding.html)

> Providing financial resources to finance a need, program, or project.
> In general, this term is used when a firm fills the need for cash from
> its own internal reserves, and the term 'financing' is used when the
> need is filled from external or borrowed money.

Or simply [**fund**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fund)

> an amount of money that is used for a special purpose
> available money : an amount of something that is available for use : a
> supply of something

You could say "I created this *fund* to accept donations/payments for X"

Also consider [**pool**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pool)

> A fund containing all the money bet in a game of chance or on the
> outcome of an event.
>
> *"big public investment pools"*

Comment: So far, "fund" seems to be the word that makes the most sense. Right now it's just a matter of figuring out if this would actually be intuitive enough for a user, but I guess this falls under a different field.

Comment: @andreiho Wait a few days and you may get better answers, friend.

Comment: I agree, it's by no means the final decision.

Answer (score 5):

To me, 'campaign' suggests something that has a limited life, like a run for president, a kickstarter project, etc - basically anything that at one point stops collecting funds (making funding in this context a rather ambiguous phrase to use as well, assuming the TS is not talking about long term product R&D).

Services and products are often longer-run endeavours, so with these differences clear, I am not sure if there is one word that can cover both scenarios without going so high level it's not intuitive anymore (there's bees, and flies and both are insects - there's campaigns and product launches, both can be considered to be undertakings..but it doesn't really say anything).

Personally, to avoid ambiguous wording that possibly lead to false expectations, advertising, law suits, etc, I would opt to have the organisation (at least in the back end) select one of the 2 systems in place: 'Create donation based project' and 'Create payment based project', where the first is where visitors can make a donation and not expect anything in return and the second where visitors can actually order a product/service.

Comment: Actually given the specifications of the project, the "limited life" aspect makes sense, because as a user I would be able to stop accepting payments or donations for a given "fund" or "campaign". Overall I agree with you, and if presenting it as 2 different things proves to be the most intuitive choice, then that's what I'll do. I guess ultimately it comes down to what the users think, so some testing might be necessary.

Comment: Glad you found something to work with in my reply :) Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 3):

How about ***drive***?

> A strong organized effort to accomplish a purpose: *a drive to finish the project before the deadline*; *fund-raising drive* [FOD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Drive)
>
> An effort made by a group of people to achieve a goal, to collect money, etc. [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drive)

Comment: It wouldn't be intuitive enough for the user. It makes sense when used in a proper sentence, but you wouldn't really be able to understand it when used as a standalone word, which is quite important.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using "fund [**account**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/account)". Account means:

> a record of debit and credit entries to cover transactions involving a
>   particular item or a particular person or concern

[Merriam-Webster]

Your example:

> To be more specific, a **fund account** can be created by an organization to...

If you use "a fund account for donation and payment", it would be more clear, but I don't see any problem using just a *fund account*.

Comment: It's a good word, in a financial context, but in my particular case the word "account" would be associated with user accounts, and it would simply conflict. Right now the best option I have is "Funds".

Comment: @andreiho Yes, but the context can help prevent confusion with user accounts. You can consider using **fund account**. I edited my post.